# How to initialize an array of arrays (or jagged array) using CodeDom?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I'm trying to use [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) to generate C# (.Net 2.0) code that would do the following:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[someSize][];
```

In CodeDom, initializing an array requires a [CodeArrayCreateExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codearraycreateexpression.aspx). The MSDN says:

> If a language allows arrays of arrays, it is possible to create them by nesting a CodeArrayCreateExpression within a CodeArrayCreateExpression.

The way I understand it, the only possibility is to write something like this:

```
  // Declaration and initialization of myArray
  CodeVariableDeclarationStatement variable =
    new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("System.Int32[][]", "myArray",
      new CodeArrayCreateExpression("System.Int32[][]",
        new CodeExpression[] { new CodeArrayCreateExpression("System.Int32[]", 0) }));
```

But this generates this:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[][] { new int[0] };
```

That's not perfect but I could do with it if I knew the size of myArray at generation time, which I don't.

I could write a function that does the initialization and call it in CodeDom but it would be nicer if I could do it in pure CodeDom. Did I miss something ?

[EDIT] Background information

The idea is to automatically generate an adapter between two object representations. I have a meta-description (some kind of IDL) saying: "I have a container object which has a field of type int[][]" and two representations of this container:

```
// Internal representation
public class InternalContainer {
  int[][] myArray;
}

// Network representation
public class NetworkContainer {
  int[][] myArray;
}
```

Thus the question of generating code that can adapt to any size of array.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following workaround to create a jagged array with a dynamic length:

Create the dom equivalent of

```
ELEMENTTYPE[] array = (ELEMENTTYPE[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(ELEMENTTYPE), length);
```

`ELEMENTTYPE` can be any type, be it an array or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, using a CodeSnippetExpression

```
public static DOM.CodeExpression NewArray (this Type type, int dim, int size) {
  string dims = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("[]", dim - 1).ToArray());
  return new DOM.CodeSnippetExpression(string.Format("new {0}[{1}]{2}", type.FullName, size, dims));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  CodeArrayCreateExpression CodeArrayCreateExpression(Array array)
  {
     CodeArrayCreateExpression arrayCreateExpression = new CodeArrayCreateExpression(array.GetType(), array.GetLength(0));

     if (array.GetType().GetElementType().IsArray)
     {
        CodeArrayCreateExpression[] values = new CodeArrayCreateExpression[array.GetLength(0)];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
           values[j] = this.CodeArrayCreateExpression((Array)array.GetValue(j));
        }

        arrayCreateExpression.Initializers.AddRange(values);
     }
     else if(array.GetType().GetElementType().IsPrimitive)
     {
        CodeCastExpression[] values = new CodeCastExpression[array.GetLength(0)];
        for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
        {
           values[j] = new CodeCastExpression();
           values[j].Expression = new CodePrimitiveExpression(array.GetValue(j));
           values[j].TargetType = new CodeTypeReference(array.GetType().GetElementType());
        }

        arrayCreateExpression.Initializers.AddRange(values);
     }

     return arrayCreateExpression;
  }
```

Comment: But I'll need to know the first dimension of the array, right ? And I can't, see my edit. Thanks anyway for the general case implementation.